# Distributed Search in Solr with different queries per shard

Tags: solr, sharding

I have 2 cores.
One with active data and one with historical data (for documents which were removed from the active one).
I want to run Distributed Search on both and get the unified result (as supported by Solr Distributed Search, I'm not using Solr Cloud).
My problem is that the query for each core is different.
Is there a way to specify different query per core and still let Solr to unify the query results?
For example:
Active data core query: select all green docs
History core query: select all green docs with DocVersion=4

- One option is to send a unified query to both but then each core will work harder for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The way Solr Distributed Search works is to pass in a shards parameter that lists the shards to run the query against. The Solr shard that you querying will then pass the same query to all solr shards listed in the shards list, wait for the results and then merge them. It has no facility to pass in different queries to each shard.

I'd read thru the documentation here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

You could write custom code to do this but that seems like overkill for your use case. I'd just take the hit of running the same query across all cores.